# Raspberry Pi as near real time digital signal processor

Tags: audio, real-time, wolfson-audio-card

I have a Pi with Wolfson Audio Card, running Raspbian with low latency kernel. Is it possible and feasible to use such a setup as a near real time digital audio processor, like a reconfigurable digital guitar stompbox?

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be achieved, but to get lowest lag possible i'd use JACK sound system. I am not sure JACK supports wolfson audio card.